# Syntax error colour for TeXstudio too light

Tags: texstudio, syntax-highlighting

I'm using TeXstudio 2.12.4 (hg 6476:3e5c3afa4719).

The following code (intentionally) produces this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \s
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can probably tell, the error syntax colouring blinds the user to the actual error in the code, and I need to close the error by pressing the red `-` circle sign, which is rather bothersome.

Is there anyway to change the colour of the erroneous syntax words (currently in yellow) *just* for syntax errors? I still want it to be yellow, for example in the case of `documentclass`. So ideally it should be pink background, black words or something. Then when I close the error (clicking the `-` circle sign), the syntax turns back to yellow?

I looked at this setting in the TeXstudio settings:

[image: err]

under line error, the background colour (middle box) is pink. But when I change the foreground colour (box to its left) to black, for example, there's no change in the colour of the `\s`..

I hope this is clear.

Comment: Have you restarted TeXstudio (sometimes it helps)?

Comment: @TeXnician Yes I have, unfortunately it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line highlighting is applied only to the background of a complete line without considering it's contents. Everything except the background color is ignored.

You should change the lightness to be similar to the normal background, e. g. a dark red in your case.